# POst data to multiple file on form submit

Tags: php, ajax

I have button inside form.
On button click, I submit form and post some var data to file.

```
<form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
```

Here is it possible to post multiple file.

Like to `data1.php` and `data2.php` in above case?

something like `showUser1()` should poast to `data1.php` and `showuser2()` to `data2.php`.

possible?

Comment: change the action attr with JavaScript

Comment: Yes, that is possible and you kind of gave the answer yourself in the tags you chose for this question: you must post the values using `ajax`, not by relying on the form submit routine.

Comment: Oh, I think you can also concatenate function calls in an inline event handler, but that really is ugly: `onsubmit="showUser1(this,event);showUser2(this,event);"`

Comment: @arkascha: your solution is interesting. Hey samitha: what you say, will it work? what arkascha told in 3rd comment!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the action of a form using JavaScript. Here, I've given your form an ID:

```
<form id="myForm" action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
```

Example JavaScript to change the action attribute of a form:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('myForm') || null;
if(frm) {
   frm.action = 'data1.php' 
}
```

or

```
var frm = document.getElementById('myForm') || null;
if(frm) {
   frm.action = 'data2.php' 
}
```

Note that this won't work if the user has decided to disable JavaScript. i.e. You can't fully rely on it.

Comment: Thanks but this will post only one either `data1.php` or `data2.php` right?

Comment: You can change it to anything that you want to: `frm.action = 'whatever-page-you-want.php'`

Comment: thanks but I could not understand how function will be called here